# Evaluating $\int_0^\infty\ln(x)e^{-x} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

For quite sometime I have been stuck. I do not know how to approach this problem. Bear with me if this is already asked:

> How can I evaluate $\int_0^\infty\ln(x)e^{-x} dx$?

My trial so far is to use integration by parts but i have no idea how to do it:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{let } U=&~\ln(x) &dv=e^{-x}dx\\
du =&~\frac{1}{x}dx&V=-e^{-x}\\
\int_0^\infty \ln(x)e^xdx  =& -\ln(x)e^{-x}{\LARGE|}_{0}^\infty +\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx
\end{aligned}
$$

But this doesn't seem right since the first part seems to go to infinity instead of a constant value. Also  iI cannot even do the second part. Using R's `integrate(function(x) log(x)*exp(-x), 0, Inf)` I get `-0.57721567` which shows that this integration exists.  Can someone help me out?

Comment: Your original integral diverges on the $\to\infty$ side, so this can't have an answer. Did you mean $e^{-x}$ ?

Comment: There seems to be a discrepancy. Is it $lnx.e^x$ or $lnx.e^{-x}$ ?

Comment: @NinadMunshi you are right. It should be $e^{-x}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant#Integrals

Comment: The value of your integral is $-\gamma$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni Constant.  It can be taken as the definition of $\gamma$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Feynman trick we have that

$$\int_0^\infty\log x \: e^{-x}\:dx = \frac{d}{da}\int_0^\infty x^a e^{-x}\:dx\Biggr|_{a=0} = \Gamma'(1)$$

where $\Gamma(a)$ is the Gamma function.

Comment: But what is $a$ ? I need to get -0.57721567 as the answer

Comment: why did you change the $log(x)$ to $x^a$ ? Are there any links? Sorry I am not that good in math. Also in my trial above, Is there a way to approach the second integral?

Comment: Thanks for the trick. Looked through and I do understand now

Comment: @Onyambu because $\log x \cdot x^a \implies \frac{d}{da}x^a$ by derivative rules. We just insert an $x^a$ in the original integral since $x^0=1$ was there all along. Your integral above is a transcendental function called exponential integral function. But the integration by parts adds a divergence at $x=0$ where none existed in the original integral.

Comment: Thanks so much. If you do not mind, could you share some light with regards to proving the exponential integral function? or do we just take that as a definition?

Comment: @Onyambu it's just a definition